# how to reload local datastore in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This used to work until about 3 months ago.

```
dev_appserver.py --storage_path=/home/stephen/webprog/trunk2/ trunk2/app.yaml
```

now it starts the server but datastore is empty. I need the DataStore as it has models and user logins. What I do now is to unzip an old trunk from 3 months ago and start the server, then change the code (not touching the DS models), then log in, test, logout and stop with C-c. if I restrat the server the DataStore will not load. How can I make it load the DataStore so that I do not need to revert to my old working trunk? I am using Google App Engine using python.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the [Local Development Server docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#using_the_local_datastore):

> We are migrating the local development environment to use the [Cloud Datastore Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator), For more information about this change, see the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/migrate-cloud-datastore-emulator).

You should follow the migration guide to use the Datastore Emulator instead

Comment: the local DS still works and my problem is not the need to migrate. INFO     2020-05-10 15:12:36,235 shutdown.py:50] Shutting down.
INFO     2020-05-10 15:12:36,237 stub_util.py:382] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2020-05-10 15:12:36,794 stub_util.py:385] Saving search indexes
INFO     2020-05-10 15:12:36,900 module.py:432] [default] Detected file changes:
  /home/stephen/webprog/trunk2/datastore.db
  /home/stephen/webprog/trunk2/datastore.db-journal
  /home/stephen/webprog/trunk2/search_indexes
  /home/stephen/webprog/trunk2/tmpWzZSyR

Comment: after starting the local server the DS viewer does not see a namespace: Datastore Viewer

Datastore has no entities in the Empty namespace. You need to add data programatically before you can use this tool to view and edit it.
Select different namespace